Array of elements condition with Jolt
How can I generate a list of addresses as output based on input properties such as "soldAddress" and "officeAddress," and include a hardcoded value such as "Primary"? The input property "officeAddress" may be empty, null, present, or missing in the input JSON. How can I achieve the desired JSON output using Jolt transformation?
Input.json
{
  "address": [
    {
      "soldAddress": "N",
      "officeAddress": "P"
    },
    {
      "soldAddress": "P",
      "officeAddress": "N"
    }
  ]
}

Actual Jolt.json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "address": {
        "*": {
          "officeAddress": {
            "P": {
              "#Home": "couries[#1].delivery.homeAddress",
              "#true": "couries[#1].delivery.isPrimary",
              "@2,soldAddress": "couries[#1].delivery.soldAddress"
            },
            "*": {
              "#Office": "couries[#1].delivery.homeAddress",
              "@2,soldAddress": "couries[#1].delivery.soldAddress"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Expected output.json
{
  "couries": [
    {
      "delivery": {
        "homeAddress": "Home",
        "isPrimary": "true",
        "soldAddress": "N"
      }
    },
    {
      "delivery": {
        "homeAddress": "Office",
        "isPrimary": "true",
        "soldAddress": "P"
      }
    }
  ]
}



No need to put the attributes isPrimary and soldAddress into the
part which is used for conditinal logic. So single definitions within the outer part would be enough per each one.
The ~ operator might be used within a modify spec to check
existence and nullability

So, you can use the following transformation :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "address": {
        "*": {
          "#true": "couries[&1].delivery.isPrimary",
          "soldAddress": "couries[&1].delivery.&",
          "officeAddress": {
            "P": {
              "#Home": "couries[&3].delivery.homeAddress"
            },
            "*": {
              "#Office": "couries[&3].delivery.homeAddress"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "couries": {
        "*": {
          "delivery": {
            "~homeAddress": "Office" // if "homeAddress" does not exist or is null, then make it be "Office"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

